# Can't create a menu without changing the runtime version?

Tags: google-apps-script

This code will not work for onopen or executed from the code editor.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('X Function')
        .addItem('Create X from X', 'rawDataReform')
        .addItem('Generate XX', 'printXXX')
        .addItem('Clear all results', 'clearTabs')        
        .addItem('Link the Tabs','importNewData')
        .addToUi();
}
```

The error I am getting says

> "this action is not supported unless the runtimeVersion is set to
>   "DEPRECATED_ES5"
>
> in the appscript.json file.

This particular code was not handled in clasp so

1) I don't know how to get to the json file and

2) how do I figure out what absolutely basic function has been randomly deprecated here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, all functions seem to give that error, if you're in V8. You might want to try later. To change your runtime back, Go to View> Show manifest file. In `appsscript.json`,  set

```
"runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"
```

and save it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('X Function')
  .addItem('Create X from X', 'rawDataReform')
  .addItem('Generate XX', 'printXXX')
  .addItem('Clear all results', 'clearTabs')        
  .addItem('Link the Tabs','importNewData')
  .addToUi();
}
```

I think the appscript.json file is displayed when you display manifest in View Menu

Comment: Which runtime version are you using? My error is from V8